# Problema con Método WebService

Tags: c#, webservice

Buen dia comunidad les pido su ayuda ya que quiero regresar una lista con un método en mi web service pero no puedo, me sale error, mi código es el siguiente:

```
    public List<Cliente> RFIDGetCteXML(string Puerto, string Multiplexor)
    {
        string puerto;
        JavaScriptSerializer serializador = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        Class1.bd();
        Class1.IniciarConexiones();
        MySqlCommand query1 = new MySqlCommand("RfidWS2", Class1.AbrirMiconexionInteligas());
        query1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        query1.Parameters.Add("@puerto", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
        query1.Parameters.Add("@multiplexor1", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
        query1.Parameters["@puerto"].Value = Puerto;
        query1.Parameters["@multiplexor1"].Value = Multiplexor;
        MySqlDataReader reader = query1.ExecuteReader();
        cte = new List<Cliente>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {             
            puerto = Convert.ToString(reader.GetInt32(1));
            cte.Add(new Cliente(Convert.ToString(registro), reader.GetString(0), puerto, reader.GetString(2), reader.GetString(3), reader.GetString(4), reader.GetString(5), reader.GetString(6), reader.GetString(7), reader.GetString(8)));
        }

        Class1.Cerrarconexionmysqlinteligas();
        return cte;
    }
```

El error es el siguiente:

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. No se puede serializar WebRFID.Cliente porque no tiene un constructor sin parámetros. Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código. Detalles de la excepción: System.InvalidOperationException: No se puede serializar WebRFID.Cliente porque no tiene un constructor sin parámetros.

Comment: Podrias aclarar cual es el error que te aparece para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [editar tu pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/61998/edit) para que ingreses más detalle de tu problema.

Comment: Del error entiendo que la clase "Cliente" tiene un único constructor que recibe parámetos; el sistema busca uno que no los tenga y por no existir lanza error; adecua lo necesario y coloca un constructor sin parámetros.

Answer (score 0):

Elimina el constructor que hayas definido en la clase quendo

```
public class Cliente
{
    public Cliente()
    {
    }

    public string registro {get;set;}
    public string puerto {get;set;}
    //resto propiedades
}
```

entonces asignas los datos usando

```
while (reader.Read())
{             
    string puerto = Convert.ToString(reader.GetInt32(1));

    Cliente cli = new Cliente()
    {
        registro = registro,
        puerto = puerto,
        //resto propiedades
    };

    cte.Add(cli);
}
```

como veras el constructor queda limpio y asignas las propiedades directamente

Comment: Muchisisisimas gracias si funciono